# How to get a video to play in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-videoview

I have spent all day trying to figure this out using libraries and everything but I can't seem to implement a feature that would seem easy.

My end goal here is to get videos to display in a recyclerview as this part of my app will have a 'videos' section.

I will attach my current code and if anyone could help i'd appreciate it all I am really using here is intent extras to get and pull data.

Adapter.java

```
public class WerecommendAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WerecommendAdapter.MyHolder> {

private final List<Businesses> mData;
private Context mcontext;
private CategoryCardActivity cca;


public WerecommendAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Businesses> mData) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}

public WerecommendAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mcontext = parent.getContext ();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from ( mcontext ).inflate ( R.layout.recommend_card_design,
            parent, false );


    return new WerecommendAdapter.MyHolder ( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

    Businesses temp = mData.get ( position );
    // Dymamically Generating card background colours
    Random rnd = new Random ();
    int currentColour = Color.argb ( 255, rnd.nextInt ( 256 ), rnd.nextInt ( 256 ), rnd.nextInt ( 256 ) );
    holder.cardview.setBackgroundColor ( currentColour );

    holder.businessname.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getBusiness_name () );
    Glide.with ( mcontext )
            .asBitmap ()
            .load ( mData.get ( position ).getBusiness_img () )
            .diskCacheStrategy ( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
            .into ( holder.businesslogo );
    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener ( v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent ( mcontext, Solocompany.class );
        intent.putExtra ( "bus_name", temp.getBusiness_name () );
        intent.putExtra ( "bdesc", temp.getBdesc () );
        intent.putExtra ( "Image_URL", temp.getBusiness_img () );
        intent.putExtra ( "contact", temp.getContact () );
        intent.putExtra ( "website", temp.getBusiness_website () );
        intent.putExtra ( "website_social", temp.getBusiness_website_social () );
        intent.putExtra ( "careers", temp.getCareers () );
        intent.putExtra ( "videos", temp.getVideos () );
        mcontext.startActivity ( intent );

        } );


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    cca = new CategoryCardActivity ();
    return mData.size ();
}


public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView category;
    RelativeLayout werecommend;
    TextView businessname;
    ImageView businesslogo;
    LinearLayout cardview;

    VideoView videoView;



    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        category = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.category );
        werecommend = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.werecommendrecycler );
        businessname = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.businessname );
        businesslogo = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.business_image );
        cardview = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.cardview );
        videoView = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.videorecycler );



    }
}
```

}

Where Intent goes ---->

```
public class Solocompany extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "SOLO company";
ImageView business_logo;
List<Businesses> businessesList;
Button website, social, careers, contact;
TextView business_name;
TextView bdesc;
VideoView videoView;



private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.company_solo_page );
    businessesList = new ArrayList<> ();
    business_name = findViewById ( R.id.bus_name );
    business_logo = findViewById ( R.id.profile_image );
    bdesc = findViewById ( R.id.bdesc );
    website = findViewById ( R.id.website );
    social = findViewById ( R.id.socialmedia );
    careers = findViewById ( R.id.careers );
    contact = findViewById ( R.id.contact );
    videoView = findViewById ( R.id.videorecycler );
    videoView.setVideoURI ( Uri.parse ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "videos" ) ) );

    business_name.setText ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "bus_name" ) );
    bdesc.setText ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "bdesc" ) );
    Glide.with ( this )
            .load ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "Image_URL" ) )
            .into ( business_logo );
    contact.setOnClickListener ( this::contact );
```

Any help would be appreciated

----------------- **UPDATE 22:34** ---------------

I am getting this error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView cannot be cast to android.widget.VideoView

Comment: VideovView and RecyclerView both are different classes and It can't be cast to one another.

Comment: If you have declared the recyclerView in XML then use RecyclerView class to keep it instance instead of VideoView.

Comment: Hi @ShahzadAfridi

What would be the best way to achieve the result of getting videos in the layout from a database?

Comment: Hello. Yes how can I help you.

Comment: Hi @ShahzadAfridi how would you suggest I pull videos from a database could i use intent extras?

Comment: You can add url/reference of uploaded video in database. we can't save video direct to database. so I will assume you will get the url then simply load that url to videoView.

Answer (score 1):

I see a possibility to get a workaround. You can set up the `RecyclerView` like [this project](https://medium.com/@Pang_Yao/android-room-recyclerview-cardview-picasso-6f2b8e079116) reffers. Then implement "[glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)" (usefull widget to get picture and GIFs from Internet site or servers)
I guess what it can do is playing thumbnail that you access from GIFs. So you implement the link from your GIF (as preview video) and Glide will play it. It wont play videos but GIFs.

I know this isn't exactly what you wanted, but better then telling you there is nothing around. Hope that helps. Cheers!